# android-saripaar v2 messageResId must be constant

Tags: android, validation, saripaar

I am new at java and android development. I will use [Android Saripaar v2 (thx at Ragunath Jawahar)](https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/android-saripaar) for validation.

I use Android Studio.

On a new clean android project with no other modules it work very well.

But on my multi modules Application I have problems with the **messageResId** property in the annotation. (*Attribute value must be constant*)

Here my code:

**build.gradle (Module: app)**

```
...
// workaround for "duplicate files during packaging of APK" issue
// see https://groups.google.com/d/msg/adt-dev/bl5Rc4Szpzg/wC8cylTWuIEJ
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
}

allprojects {
     repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "http://files.couchbase.com/maven2/" }
     }
 }

 dependencies {
     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
     compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
     compile project(':auth')
 }
...
```

**build.gradle (Module: auth)**

```
 dependencies {
      compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
      compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
      compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.21.1'
      compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
      compile 'com.mobsandgeeks:android-saripaar:2.0-SNAPSHOT'
      compile project (':other_api_module')
 }
```

**auth/java/.../SignInFragment.java** ERROR IN THIS FILE

```
 public class SignInFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnFocusChangeListener, Validator.ValidationListener{

 String TAG = SignInFragment.class.getName();
 private ISignInFragment iSignInFragment;

 @Email(messageResId = R.string.editTextEmailValidationError) //ERROR: Attribute (R.string.editTextEmailValidationError) value must be constant
 private EditText editTextEmail;
 private EditText editTextPassword;
 static public String EMAIL = "email";
```

Comment: Hi, are you using Saripaar in a library project?

Comment: Hallo,  No for an application. I will using it in an auth module for validation of editText fields.

Comment: Is the auth module a library project?

Comment: @RagunathJawahar Yes auth is a module with source code and resources.

Comment: Also, I believe it is a library module which is compiled along with other modules. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes That is correct. I find out, that android studio modules always first compiled along into a temporary JAR file. 
http://www.sitepoint.com/getting-started-with-android-library-projects-part-1/

Comment: Hi, you cannot use any Annotation based library / framework that requires Android resources with library modules. You have to use it with an application module instead.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use annotations that require Android resource identifiers for their attributes in library modules. You can only use them with application modules.

Resource identifiers in library modules are not final. On the other hand, resource identifiers in application modules are final. Java annotations accept only constants (final variables) for attribute values.